# Redirecting a user in a django template

Tags: python, django, redirect, django-templates, user-controls

I have a django website that is spilt depending on what user type you are, I need to redirect users that are not entitled to see certain aspects of the site,

in my template, I have:

```
{% if user.get_profile.is_store %}
    <!--DO SOME LOGIC-->
{%endif%}
```

how would I go about redirecting said store back to the index of the site?

====EDIT====

```py
def downloads(request):
    """
    Downloads page, a user facing page for the trade members to downloads POS etc
    """
    if not authenticated_user(request):
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/professional/")

    if request.user.get_profile().is_store():
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")

    user = request.user
    account = user.get_profile()

    downloads_list = TradeDownloads.objects.filter(online=1)[:6]
    downloads_list[0].get_thumbnail()
    data = {}
    data['download_list'] = downloads_list

    return render_to_response('downloads.html', data, RequestContext(request))
```

I implement the answer from thornomad, and now I get his error

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/professional/downloads
Django Version: 1.1.1
Python Version: 2.6.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'sico.news',
 'sico.store_locator',
 'sico.css_switch',
 'sico.professional',
 'sico.contact',
 'sico.shop',
 'tinymce',
 'captcha']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  92.                 response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/var/www/sico/src/sico/../sico/professional/views.py" in downloads
  78.   if request.user.get_profile().is_store():
File "/var/www/sico/src/sico/../sico/shop/models.py" in is_store
  988.         return not self.account is None
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in __get__
  191.             rel_obj = self.related.model._base_manager.get(**params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in get
  120.         return self.get_query_set().get(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in get
  305.                     % self.model._meta.object_name)

Exception Type: DoesNotExist at /professional/downloads
Exception Value: Account matching query does not exist.
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You will want to do this, I think, in a *view* not in the *template*.  So, something like:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def myview(request):
    if request.user.get_profile().is_store():
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/path/")

    # return regular view otherwise
```

You could also use a `@decorator` for the view if you found yourself needing to do this a lot.

Comment: I can think of some valid cases where you want the template to determine whether to redirect.  Most occur when the template author has some page-specific logic that determines that you have to view some other page before viewing this page.

Comment: +1 @GregGlockner To add another case : When you are overriding a template from a 3rd party library. It's easier to redirect in template in some cases than override the view because you are customizing the former anyway.

Answer (score 17):

Use the HTML's raw redirection.

```
{% if user.get_profile.is_store %}
    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://redirect-url">
{% endif %}
```

or provide the redirection url as a context variable

```
{% if user.get_profile.is_store %}
    <meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url={{ user.get_profile.store_url }}">
{% endif %}
```

if memory serves right, this has to be inside the "head" tag, but modern browser are more forgiving, Firefox 4 allowed it inside the "body" tag and worked ok.

Answer (score 5):

You really don't want to redirect in a template, as said in all other answers.

But if redirecting in a view is no option (why ever), you can do this:

```
{% if user.get_profile.is_store %}
    {% include '/path/to/template' %}
{% else %}
    {% include '/path/to/another_template' %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 5):

Of course sometimes we have views imported from django official code, or others that does not depend on us. We cannot place a redirect in those views, so the only way is through a template that these (untouchable) views are using.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might want to do the redirect in the view code.

For example, this would work in Django 1.1.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def my_view(request):
    if request.user.get_profile().is_store:
        return redirect('index')
    # normal view code here
    return ....
```

Documentation for redirect shortcut is here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/ The arguments to redirect() can be (quoting the docs):

- A model: the model's get_absolute_url() function will be called.
- A view name, possibly with arguments: urlresolvers.reverse() will be used to reverse-resolve the name.
- A URL, which will be used as-is for the redirect location.

Answer (score 1):

You wouldn't do this in the template, but in the view. Instead of calling render_to_response (which I presume you do now), you would call [HttpResponseRedirect](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/).

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect with [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location), [location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href),[location.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/assign) and [location.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) in JavaScript in Django Templates as shown below. *`location`, `location.href` and `location.assign()` redirect to the URL adding the record to the history so we can go back to the previous page while `location.replace()` redirects to the URL not adding the record to the history so we cannot go back to the previous page:

```
<script>
{% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
    location = "{% url '/professional/' %}";
{%endif%}
{% if request.user.get_profile.is_store %}
    location = "{% url '/' %}";
{%endif%}
</script>
```

```
<script>
{% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
    location.href = "{% url '/professional/' %}";
{%endif%}
{% if request.user.get_profile.is_store %}
    location.href = "{% url '/' %}";
{%endif%}
</script>
```

```
<script>
{% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
    location.assign("{% url '/professional/' %}");
{%endif%}
{% if request.user.get_profile.is_store %}
    location.assign("{% url '/' %}");
{%endif%}
</script>
```

```
<script>
{% if not request.user.is_authenticated %}
    location.replace("{% url '/professional/' %}");
{%endif%}
{% if request.user.get_profile.is_store %}
    location.replace("{% url '/' %}");
{%endif%}
</script>
```